# Setting ActionBar Menu Items Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I am just getting started with Android. I want to add an `ActionBar` menu to my small tip calculator application. I have set up the menu xml file. When I run the application on my mobile device, the part where the menu is supposed to appear, is blank.

My `onCreate` Method does not have the `setActionBar()` method, so I think the problem could lie there??

Here is the code for my `onCreate` Method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    serviceLevelSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.serviceLevelSpinner);
```

**Menu.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<item android:id = "@+id/aboutLink" android:title = "@string/applicationAbout" app:showAsAction = "always" android:icon = "@drawable/ic_mymenu"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: your `menu.xml` file?

Comment: where you implemented oncreateOptionsmenu() ? http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Comment: Which device are you using for testing? The display of action icons also depends on the width of the device!

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you **extends** the **ActionbarActivity** to make the **Activity** or simple **Activity**.  To has the functionality of **Actionbar** you need to **extends** the **ActionbarActivity**. And then your code will work fine with the menu items.

Answer (score 0):

First ensure that your Activity extends **AppCompatActivity**. Next, add a **Toolbar** to your Activity's layout file. Call the **setSupportActionBar(toolbar)** method in **onCreate**. The parameter used should be an instance of the Toolbar from your layout.

Note that in your styles.xml file, you have to set the **windowActionBar** item to **false** or use a theme with **parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"** to avoid errors from duplicate toolbars.